# Private WordPress Content

Tags: plugins

I will send customers a QR CODE that will direct them to an image on the website (png or pdf), referring to their circuit.

Example: https://inovative.com.br/qr-code/Customer1/
https://inovative.com.br/qr-code/Customer2/

Customer 1 will access image 1 via QR code
Customer 2 will access image 2 via QR code

And so on, that is, client 1 cannot view image 2, even if he changes the url in the browser search.

How can I do this? Whether with code or plugins

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.